# TortoiseSVN version for windows XP

Tags: tortoisesvn

Which is the latest version of TortoiseSVN is compatible with Windows XP service pack 3?

I just installed its latest build 1.9.3 but unfortunately it's not supported in windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TSVN 1.8.x are the latest versions that support Windows XP, because Subversion 1.9 removed XP support. So get the latest [version 1.8.9 from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.8.9/).

Answer (score 6):

[1.8.12](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.8.12/Application/) is the latest release in branch 1.8, 1.8.10 was released because 1.8.9

> BUG: Fails to run on Windows XP.

and, btw, 1.8.11 had a lot of important bugfixes (contrary to minor corrections in 1.8.12)

Comment: I had installed 1.8.11 and it worked fine.. I mean I haven't used it extremely well but it works.

Comment: @CodeFinder - yes, "TortoiseSVN 1.8.11, Build 26392 - 32 Bit" is my main SVN-tool on my XP

Comment: Yeah It is... I'm currently trying to put our stuff to version control using WaspSVN plugin and our company made very complicated IDE and it's so chaotic... :(

Comment: You must install `Windows Installer 4.5` (`WindowsXP-KB942228-v3-x86` and `windowsserver2003-kb942288-v4-x64`), but it is no longer available in MS Update Catalog (https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb942288), nor MS Support (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-installer-4-5-is-available-bf06be18-3e0a-d5eb-4549-b482f67e1c46).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download v 1.7 
Here is the link:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/?source=typ_redirect